# Обход кода 503 при парсинге

Tags: python, requests

Я пытаюсь спарсить страницу, например данную: https://simpletire.com/paid?brand=bridgestone&cjdata=MXxOfDB8WXww&cjevent=fe83658f5b6911ed81df001a0a18b8fc&delivery=Del3&itemId=2696&mpn=206310&productLine=duravis-m700-hd&tireSize=lt245-75r16&utm_campaign=14463641&utm_content=CJ+Test+Style+Blog+-+2&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=cj&utm_term=1&v=1

При отправке запроса, он возвращает 503

Вот пример запроса;

```
url = 'https://simpletire.com/paid?brand=bridgestone&cjdata=MXxOfDB8WXww&cjevent=fe83658f5b6911ed81df001a0a18b8fc&delivery=Del3&itemId=2696&mpn=206310&productLine=duravis-m700-hd&tireSize=lt245-75r16&utm_campaign=14463641&utm_content=CJ+Test+Style+Blog+-+2&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=cj&utm_term=1&v=1'

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.'
                  '124 YaBrowser/22.9.5.710 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(req.status_code)
}
```

Подскажите может как изменить заголовки?

Comment: Добавте cookies с ключом  '__cf_bm'

Comment: Не помогло данное добавление

Comment: Значить что-то сделали не так

Comment: headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '__cf_bm',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.'
                  '124 YaBrowser/22.9.5.710 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}

Данный набор заголовков не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Как пример(У меня работает):

```
import requests

cookies = {
        '__cf_bm': 'kwDUv7.UUIxzIqwhT5085lk9M8qejI_R0ft8PW_N2GA-1667480182-0-'
                   'Af0TUNwF4H1EuXq/lHiPvFIo7iGQijyVmDYWQmLsND4HABAc9lYyaqGNW+vf5aKmx/HqRtvvIXOE34cYTBXJKJw='
}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0'}

response = requests.get('https://simpletire.com/paid?'
                        'brand=bridgestone&cjdata=MXxOfDB8WXww&cjevent=fe83658f5b6911ed81df001a0a18b8fc&'
                        'delivery=Del3&itemId=2696&mpn=206310&productLine=duravis-m700-hd&tireSize=lt245-75r16&'
                        'utm_campaign=14463641&utm_content=CJ+Test+Style+Blog+-+2&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=cj&'
                        'utm_term=1&v=1', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
print(response)

<Response [200]>
```